# sql server - Update , C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql, update

Hola quería hacer una consulta a ver si pueden ayudarte, quiero modificar un campo cantidad de unidades vendidas el condicional "where" es el stock que tiene el producto

ej: se vendieron 4 unidades quiero modificar esa venta a 5 unidades y el stock del producto(otra tabla) es 1 como seria el "where" para que se cumpla la condición de que no se puede vender mas del stock que hay.

otro ej: se venden 4 unidades quiero modificar lo a 2 unidades debería dejar avanzar por que es menor, pero si yo al "where" lo hago con que  la cantidad a  vender no puede ser menor al stock del producto no me va a dejar avanzar.
como debería hacerlo para que funcionara ante las diferentes opciones que se presenten

-que la cantidad a modificar sea menor que la registra en la venta inicial.
-que la cantidad a modificar sea mayor que la registra en la venta inicial.
-y el stock que sume la cantidad que se le resta si es menor la cantidad a la registrada.
- y que se le reste el stock si la cantidad a modificar es mayor a la vendida inicialmente.

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a StackOverflow, añade tu código(el que as intentado) y estructura de tabla para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: `ALTER Proc [dbo].[ActualizarDetalleVenta]
@idprod int,
@idventa int,
@cantidad int,
@subTotal decimal(10,2),
@Mensaje Varchar(100) Out
As Begin
 Declare @Stock As Int
 Set @Stock=(Select stock From producto Where id_producto=@idprod)
 Begin
 update Detalle_venta set cantidad=@cantidad,subtotal=@subTotal
 where id_prod=@idprod and id_venta=@idventa
 Set @Mensaje='Registro Actualizado Correctamente.'
 end
 update producto set stock=@Stock-@cantidad where id_producto=@idprod
 end`

Comment: El problema es que si la nueva cantidad a vender es menor que la cantidad registrada inicialmente, ya no se le va a poder restar la cantidad sino que va tener que sumar la diferencia y no se como podria  hacerlo